# How do I achieve the simple background effect as shown in the image using CSS?

Tags: css, sass

Here is the [image](https://s21.postimg.org/e7mp14ytj/Untitled_1.jpg).

How to do this double background effect? If possible, without splitting the overlaying div which contains the personal info and social links.

Comment: This can be done in so many ways. Post what you have done so far and we suggest based on that

Comment: I haven't done it but I am thinking of simply making a separate div which contains the content over the dark background. But that feels like splitting what should be one section. Please just post your solution as you feel.

Comment: @LGSon Accepted :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and one that will scale with content is a pseudo element, here used `::before`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}
.parent::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 60%;
  background: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}
.child {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this is by using the `linear-gradient` for the `background` of the element.

Like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #49565f, #49565f 50%, #fff 50%, #fff);
```

You can see a demo of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f6Lc9rrh/).

**UPDATE**

If you want to limit the size of the first stripe so its not always 50% you can set a `background-size: 100% Xpx` (Xpx being the height you want) and then set `background-repeat: no-repeat;` so it won't repeat.

See a demo of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f6Lc9rrh/2/).

Comment: It's not 50% height for lighter background. There is more content down.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPathania see if my update helps at all

Comment: I think it still does not work because the other color of gradient is not white but a lighter grey #efefef. That grey needs to fill the rest of the background of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div with a lower `z-index` with that background color, so technically you'd have:

```
body { 
background-color: Gray; }
.dark-div { 
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: DimGray; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: n px; // not sure what height should be }
.content-div {
  z-index: 10; }
```

Edit: Didn't realize you meant background for the *content* and not the body. If you're trying to do it with the content div, you'll have to make sure the social links height and the bottom background-color always match up. You can do this with % or em values.

Comment: How to do it if we don't know the height?